# sh script escaping

Tags: linux, sh

From a linux terminal the command:

```
 ls application/js/{a*,b*,c*,d*,e.pocket-secure}
```

Will list all files in the application/js directory that start with a,b,c,d or e.pocket-secure.

If I place that command in doit.sh and execute:

```
sh doit.sh
```

I get:

```
ls: cannot access application/js/{a*,b*,c*,d*,e.pocket-secure*}: No such file or directory
```

I think the {} is confusing the shell interpreter, but I tried quoting (single|double) and also tried escaping the {} to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

When you type it in the terminal, I suspect that you are in `bash`.  When you run `sh doit.sh`, you are  changing the characteristics of the shell, either because `bash` is in compatibility mode or because you are using something like `dash`.  Try doing `bash doit.sh`.

Comment: What you suggested does work, but it is part of a 2-300 line script that I dont want to rewrite/recheck to convert to a different interpreter.

Comment: if this is the case, by adding  following to the script it will be resolved: #! /bin/sh'

Comment: If you need to stick with `sh`, then you may have to use 5 separate `ls` commands and then combine the results.

Comment: #!/bin/sh was already at the start. At this stage I'm doing this: 

    echo "ls application/js/{a*,b*,c*,d*,e.pocket-secure*}" | bash

Answer (score 1):

this syntax work only with bash interpretor you can try this

```
#/bin/bash
ls application/js/{a*,b*,c*,d*,e.pocket-secure}
```

and

```
chmod +x doit.sh
./doit.sh
```

OR

just type this on shell

```
bash doit.sh
```